# Android Listview background image shows on each row, why?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListActivity with a ListView and everything works great; however I am trying to set a background image and the image is appearing in each row and making the row very tall.

How do I make the background for that view so the rows don't pick up the image?

Answer (score 11):

In onCreate() of your ListActivity, call

```
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
    getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundresource);
```

Without the .setCacheColorHint(0) the background will flash to the original background color every time you scroll. With it added the background is a constant. (Thanks Matt it fixed that issue for me).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are attaching the background to the list item, be sure to do this in your ListActivity:

```
getListView().setBackgroundResource(...)
```